# Listening for session-events not working after update to SpringBoot2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project that uses spring with spring boot. It features some custom security mechanism as well as listening to session-creation and
session-destruction events:

```
@WebListener
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        System.out.println("==== Session is created ====");

        //sets a custom session timeout
        httpSessionEvent.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(10);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        System.out.println("==== Session is destroyed ====");
    }
}
```

instanciated via:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
import sample.session.MySessionListener;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

public class WebAppInitializer implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        //only https allowed
        //servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(true);

        //add session listener for example to influence session-timeout
        servletContext.addListener(new MySessionListener());
    }
}
```

with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Class[] { SpringSecApp.class, WebAppInitializer.class }, args);
    }
}
```

Now I added some configuration to make spring write session-information to a MySql DB. To achieve that I had to update my pom.xml from Spring-Boot 1.5.x to 2.1.3 .

Now this session-info-writing works fine but I recognized that the session-events are not handled anymore; I suppose that the cause lies in the dependencies as I didn't alter the relevant code pieces concerning the session-listening that I posted above but I was not able to find it. I would be grateful for any help! I will include 2 pom-versions; first the current one and then one from the last commit in which I can confirm that session-event-handling works fine.
Current version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bous.philipp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-custom-auth-userdetails-REST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!--Workaround for broken openjdk-version-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Previous version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bous.philipp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-custom-auth-userdetails-REST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!--Workaround for broken openjdk-version-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

EDIT: I tried MyTwoCents approach which didn't change anything; furthermore it seems that the *onStartup*-Method is not being executed at all (prints to standard-out from this method don't show up).

EDIT2: I can confirm that the *onStartup*-Method of the ServletContextInitializer is being called but *MySessionListener*'s *sessionCreated* and *sessionDestroyed* are not being called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to do this way

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addListener(new MySessionListener());

        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Also a note [from Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ServletContextInitializer.html)

> Interface used to configure a Servlet 3.0+ context programmatically.
>   Unlike WebApplicationInitializer, classes that implement this
>   interface (and do not implement WebApplicationInitializer) will not be
>   detected by SpringServletContainerInitializer and hence will not be
>   automatically bootstrapped by the Servlet container.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; unfortunately your approach didn't change anything. Still no errors or visible exceptions...so I am thankful for any input. It doesn't even seem to execute the onStartup-method.

Comment: I found a similar solution at https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-session-listener/  The difference to the question's code is the additional @ServletComponentScan. Maybe try again with this annotation instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is proper handling of this issue, but it turned out that
the question itself is not appropriate as the underlying reason was not switching
from boot 1 to boot 2 but rather the reason why I switched and that was to use
a JDBC-Session-Repository.

And in this context we can refer to:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#api-jdbcoperationssessionrepository

which tells us:

*Please note that this implementation does not support publishing of session events.*

So the question does not really fit the problem but I wanted to post this for people who might come from a similar direction, even if it is not an acceptable answer.
That also means that changing the title to something like "how to work around..."
would rather draw a badly retraceable post-history which I want to avoid. I will open a more appropriate question.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works

```
public class SessionExpirationListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
//your code
    }
}
```